# Generating a unique ID with O(1) space?

Tags: algorithm

We have a group of objects, let's call them Players. We can traverse through this group only with **random** order, e.g. there is no such thing as `Players[0]`.

Each Player has a unique `ID`, with `ID < len(Players)`. Player's can be added and removed to the group. When a Player gets removed it will free his `ID`, and if a Player gets added it will acquire an `ID`.

If we want to add a new Player to Players we have to generate a new unique `ID`. What is the fastest way to generate such `ID` in O(1) space?

Comment: Why would you think there is an O(1) algorithm for this?

Comment: What's wrong with a SEQUENCE, or the non-database equivalent, like a global variable or something?  `ID = ++last_highest;`

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: the first is nothing wrong with, this is a problem I came up with after a real-life scenario, and the second wouldn't accomodate for gaps.

Comment: Since your input size is more or less fixed (bounded by a constant) there's no real "n" here so it doesn't yet make sense to talk about O(1) algorithms. (Well, the trivial algorithm is "O(1)" in this sense.) What is your requirement, more specifically?

Comment: Keep a list, of freed `id`'s and pop from the list every time you need a new one?

Comment: @Paul Eventually the sequence will top at 1000, what happens then?

Comment: O(1) **space** just means that your algorithm will use a constant amount of space (constant not 1). This means you can keep a 1000 array to mark the used ID (constant space).

Comment: @Matteo: Well, let me rephrase the question then.

Comment: tjm's methood is O(1) (set aside a stack of size 1000) and unit time, too.  I like it.

Comment: I updated the question with instead of `1000`, `n`.

Comment: "Less than N, for a certain (constant) N" doesn't change the problem.

Comment: It would've been better to explain that your solution can't involve a side-array keeping track of the "freeness" of each ID, than to change 1000 to N.

Comment: @Ira Baxter: I updated the question once again, I think this would be better suited.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen:  He might add that constraint, but it is a pointless constraint, because he is already paying for space proportional to that side array by virtue of having Players.

Comment: Are you guys really picky or just stupid? Of course I meant without any side-array or additional O(Players) data. Trying to get around those limitations with arguing or saying the question is faulty doesn't answer the problem whatsoever.

Comment: @drdwilcox: Andre Holzner already posted one.

Comment: @nightcracker: when *you* say O(1), you make certain solutions fair game.  I think your remark is uncalled for.

Comment: @Ira Baxter: Say you have a "side-array" with thousand elements while we have 100000 players. Won't work.

Comment: speaking of removing elements: how do you guarantee `ID < len(Players)` after **removing** an element ?

Comment: Oh dear god. This question wasn't well thought-through and phrased by me. I've flagged it for moderator attention to get it removed and maybe later I will post a new more thought through version.

Comment: @nightcracker: since `ID < len(Players)`, when a player get **removed**, unless his id is `len(Players)-1`, there must be a player whose ID is `len(Players)-1` ([the pigenhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)), and it will not satisfy the constraint anymore. How do you define the behavior in this situation? Is the constraint only applies when attaching an ID, and not during the whole run of the program?

Comment: Why would you want your IDs to be densely packed and reused like this? It seems like you're inventing problems for yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O(n log n) is possible with binary search. Start with a = 0 and b = n. The invariant is that there exists a free id in the interval [a, b). Repeat the following until b - a = 1: let m = a + floor((b - a) / 2), count the number of ids in [a, m) and in [m, b). If [a, m) has fewer than m - a ids, then set b = m. Otherwise, set a = m.

Comment: @Andre Holzner It's not recursive, so no. It uses O(log n) bits to store O(1) ids, but it's hard to imagine a solution that doesn't.

Comment: yes, I realized that and therefore deleted my comment. And after thinking a bit, I upvoted this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a Queue to enqueue the IDs that have been free'd up. Dequeue the queue to get free IDs once you have used up the highest possible ID. This will take O(1).

```
int highestIndex = 0;
```

Adding Players

```
if (highestIndex < len(Players)-1){
    ID = ++highestIndex();
} 
else if (!queue.isEmpty()){
    ID = queue.dequeue();
} else{
    // max players reached
}
```

Removing Players

```
queue.enqueue(ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on question as first posed with a fixed maximum number of Players:

1) Technically the size of Players is O(1).  Build a boolen array of 1000 slots, one per player, with TRUE meaning "ID is assigned".  When a player dies, set the ID for his bit to false.  When a new player arrives, search the bit array for a "false" bit; assign that ID to the player and set the bit.

Time is O(1), too with a big constant.

Based on question as revised with arbitrary N players:

2) Expanding Holzer's idea:  keep a small fixed size array of size k < < N as a cache of free IDs. Use it the way TMJ described. [TMJ deleted his answer: it said in effect, "keep a stack of unused IDs, pop an unused one, push newly dead ones"]  If the cache is empty when a new ID is needed, apply Holzer's scheme (one could even refill the small array while executing Holzer's scheme). [Sheesh, Holzer deleted his answer too, it said "try each ID in order and search the set; if nobody has that ID, use it" (O(N^2)] If the number of players arrives at more or less a steady state, this would be pretty fast because statistically there would always be some values in the fixed size array.

You can combine TMJ's idea with Per's idea, but you can't refill the array during Per's scan, only with dead player IDs.

Comment: I updated the question, `1000` is no longer the limit, `n` is.

Comment: please re-read the question. No "small fixed size array" is big enough unless they turn O(n).

Comment: So, after more edits, you've removed the "certain N" and switched to "arbitrary N".  I answered the question originally as you posed it originally.  I've added to my answer to meet your revised requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a boolean array. Construct a binary tree over this array, such that the leafs are the initial values in the array, and for items i, i+1 the parent is their logical AND (this means one of them is 0). When you want to insert traverse the tree from the root down to find the first empty slot (keep going left while one child is 0). This gives the first empty slot in O(log(n)). You can get O(log(log(n)) if you take each sqrt(n) group of bits and form an AND parent.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the players in a (cyclic) linked list. Deleting a player would involve cutting it out of the chain, and inserting it into another list (the "free" list). Allocating a player would cut (a random) one out of the "free" list and insert it into the "active" list.

UPDATE:
Since the array is fixed, you can use a watermark separating the allocated from the free players:

- Initially {watermark = 0}
- Free: {swap [this] <--> [watermark -1] ; decrement watermark; }
- Allocate: {increment watermark; yield warermark-1; }

Voila!

Answer (score -1):

Your question is ill-formed. The immediate answer is:

```
ID(newPlayer) = 1000
```

(You stated no requirement that the new player `ID` have to be less than 1000.)

More seriously, since `O(1000) == O(1)`, you can create an array of `id_seen[1000]`, mark all `ID`s you've seen so far in it, than select one you have not seen.

To make your question interesting, you have to formulate it carefully, e.g. "there are `N` players with `ID`s < `K`. You can only traverse the collection in unknown order. Add a new player with `ID < K`, using `O(1)` space."

One (inefficient) answer: select random number `X < K`. Traverse the collection. If you see a player with `ID == X`, restart. If you don't, use it as the new `ID`.

Evaluating efficiency of this algorithm for a given `N` and `K` is left as an exercise to the reader ;-)

Comment: 1. This isn't guaranteed to be unique if there are any unique ID's available, and `1000 < 1000` is not true. Also, I updated the question so you might want to remove this.

Comment: I don't want to remove this, because it's a perfectly valid answer. Your restatement of the question is *still* ill-formed (as of now).